# In Latest WooCommerce How I set Hard crop for Single Product Image

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, crop

In latest WooCommerce  there is no option to enable hard crop for single product image on WooCommerce settings area.So that i have written a function in function.php for enabling hard crop for single image.

```
function ne_theme_setup() {
    add_image_size( 'single-product', 600, 600, true );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'ne_theme_setup' );

function custom_product_large_thumbnail_size()    {
    return 'single-product';
}
add_filter('woocommerce_gallery_image_size', 'custom_product_large_thumbnail_size');
```

this code is working but when i select variable on single product page at that time image is changing and showing uncropped version of image.

How i solve this issue ? I want to display single image with 600X600 with hard crop for all variations of product.

Comment: Using the WP customizer and selecting in the custumizer the related single product page. That will make appear the image options since Woocommerce 3.3.

Comment: Yeah i know that but on that option there is no option to hard crop image in single product page

Comment: @LoicTheAztec https://ness-test.wphero.io/product/dried-chamomile-flowers/

Comment: Where that i didnt found that

Comment: https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/12/11/wc-3-3-image-size-improvements/

Comment: is that only for thumbnail cropping i want cropping for single product image that is main image

Comment: There is no cropping option for full size main image. this need to be done before uploading it in WP/WC, Or you can edit the main image and crop it in Wordpress. But the best way is to do it before uploading.

Comment: Is there any function for that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i founded solution for my issue.I added below code in function.php. After that i regenerated all images using regenerate thumbnail plugin. Its working for me!!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_single', 'my_set_product_img_size' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_shop_single', 'my_set_product_img_size' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_woocommerce_single', 'my_set_product_img_size' );
function my_set_product_img_size()
{
    $size = array(
        'width'  => 600,
        'height' => 600,
        'crop'   => 1,
    );
    return $size;
}
```

Comment: This is great but you don't need the first two `add_filter` lines. :) Just `add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_woocommerce_single', 'my_set_product_img_size' );
`